# Mail. open socket and see if it's available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a new rails 3.1.rc6 app.  I am using actionmailer.  Before I send a mail I want to connect to postfix to determine if a socket is available.  If it's not available I will run the job later.  I do not want to set

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

This would involve a connection to the socket until the email is sent.  Instead I just want to see if the socket is available and if it is I will assume everything works.

Thanks in advance.
Dave